# change textbox value in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using this gridview, I have one header checkbox and one column containing textbox. I want that when i check the header checkbox the value of every textbox changes from 0 to 1.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdData" runat="server" style="Text-align:center;">
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
      </ItemTemplate>
      <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" OnClick="CheckAllEmp(this)"/>
      </HeaderTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField>
      <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Status_Header" runat="server" Text="Status" />
      </HeaderTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:TextBox>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Do you want to do this in javascript on the clientside or with a postback?

Comment: I think correctly, that you have a **WEB** application? If **WEB** then, what prevents use, for example, **JQuery**?

Comment: Johnidol I want to do this using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using Jquery.

Not tested with the actual data, but hope this should work for you.

```
 $(function () {
        $('#CheckBox2').change(function () {
            $("#TextBox1").val(($(this).is(':checked')) ? "1" : "0");
        });
    });
```

Also you must need to add jquery plugin right before the javascript code which I gaved u. Below is one of the plugin which you can use

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

Do let us know if it works or not

Comment: Please take into account that the controls are within an `<asp:GridView>` (i.e. there is no `#CheckBox2`, etc)

Comment: @freefaller: as per OP's code, I guess there is a `#checkbox2`. which is inside gridview